# remove touch on [[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm hoping a second set of eyes on this will tell me what I'm missing.
I have three SKSpritenodes, called RubyL, RubyM and RubyR that "disappear" when touched.

The problem that I'm facing is that, even if the ndoe disappears and I remove it from the parent, my code still thinks that touches are enabled on that specific node, which disables touches on the other two nodes.

I.e. if I touched [[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:RubyL] and the sprite disappears from view it still thinks that RubyL is still active.

How do I remove the touch?

```
- (void)Rubies{

    _RubyR = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ruby"];
    _RubyR.size = CGSizeMake(self.size.width / 20.5, self.size.height / 10.4);
    _RubyR.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.1, self.size.height / -3.35);
    _RubyR.zPosition = 10;
    [self addChild:_RubyR];
    [_RubyR setName:RubyR];

    _RubyM = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ruby"];
    _RubyM.size = CGSizeMake(self.size.width / 20.5, self.size.height / 10.4);
    _RubyM.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.36, self.size.height / -3.35);
    _RubyM.zPosition = 10;
    [self addChild:_RubyM];
    [_RubyM setName:RubyM];

    _RubyL = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ruby"];
    _RubyL.size = CGSizeMake(self.size.width / 20.5, self.size.height / 10.4);
    _RubyL.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.7, self.size.height / -3.35);
    _RubyL.zPosition = 10;
    [self addChild:_RubyL];
    [_RubyL setName:RubyL];

}

- (void)removeRubyWhenBrickIsTouched: (BOOL)touched{

    NSLog(@"removeRubyWhenBrickIsTouched");

    if(touched == YES && _ActivatedRR == YES && _ActivatedRM == NO && _ActivatedRL == NO){
        NSLog(@"touched == YES && _ActivatedRR == YES");
    }

    if(touched == YES && _ActivatedRM == YES && _ActivatedRR == NO && _ActivatedRL == NO){
        NSLog(@"touched == YES && _ActivatedRM == YES");
    }

    if(touched == YES && _ActivatedRL == YES && _ActivatedRM == NO && _ActivatedRR == NO){
        NSLog(@"touched == YES && _ActivatedRL == YES");
        //putting a scaling animation on the ruby sprite to shrink its size.
        //When the animation is done, you remove the sprite from the cookie layer.
        SKAction *scaleAction = [SKAction scaleTo:0.1 duration:0.3];
        scaleAction.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;
        [_RubyL runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[scaleAction, [SKAction removeFromParent]]]];

        //removing the link between the ruby and its sprite as soon as you’ve added the animation.
        _RubyL = nil;
        _RubyM.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _RubyR.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _RubyL.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        _TouchOnRubyRL = NO;
        _ActivatedRL = NO;

        [self RubyPulse];
        [self.level ActivatedBricks:_TouchOnRubyRL];
    }
}
- (void)selectNodeForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation {

    //...asks your scene (self) for the node that is on the position touchLocation.
    SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];
    NSLog(@"selectNodeForTouch:");

    //Then the if-statement checks if the selected node is one of the ruby nodes, and activates or deactivates it.
    if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:RubyR]) {
        NSLog(@"RubyR");
        if(_TouchOnRubyRR == YES){
            NSLog(@"RubyR Not Activated");
            _ActivatedRR = NO;
            _TouchOnRubyRR = NO;
            _RubyM.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            _RubyL.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            [self RubyPulse];
            [self.level ActivatedBricks:_TouchOnRubyRR];
        }
        else if(_TouchOnRubyRR == NO){
            _ActivatedRR = YES;
            _TouchOnRubyRR = YES;
            _RubyM.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            _RubyL.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            NSLog(@"RubyR Now Activated");
            [self RubyPulse];
            [self.level ActivatedBricks:_TouchOnRubyRR];
        }
    }
    else if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:RubyM]){
        NSLog(@"RubyM");
        if(_TouchOnRubyRM == YES){
            NSLog(@"RubyM Not Activated");
            _ActivatedRM = NO;
            _TouchOnRubyRM = NO;
            _RubyL.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            _RubyR.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            [self RubyPulse];
            [self.level ActivatedBricks:_TouchOnRubyRM];
        }
        else if(_TouchOnRubyRM == NO){
            _ActivatedRM = YES;
            _TouchOnRubyRM = YES;
            _RubyL.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            _RubyR.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            NSLog(@"RubyM Now Activated");
            [self RubyPulse];
            [self.level ActivatedBricks:_TouchOnRubyRM];
        }
    }
    else if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:RubyL]){
        NSLog(@"RubyL");
        if(_TouchOnRubyRL == YES){
            NSLog(@"RubyL Not Activated");
            _ActivatedRL = NO;
            _TouchOnRubyRL = NO;
            _RubyM.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            _RubyR.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            [self RubyPulse];
            [self.level ActivatedBricks:_TouchOnRubyRL];

        }
        else if(_TouchOnRubyRL == NO){
            _ActivatedRL = YES;
            _TouchOnRubyRL = YES;
            _RubyM.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            _RubyR.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            NSLog(@"RubyL Now Activated");
            [self RubyPulse];
            [self.level ActivatedBricks:_TouchOnRubyRL];

        }

    }

}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 CGPoint Rubyposition = [touch locationInNode:self];
    [self selectNodeForTouch:Rubyposition];
    // it finds out if the touch is inside a square on the level grid and one of the rubies have been touched.
    // If so, then this might be the start of a activation effect.
    if ([self convertPoint:location toColumn:&column row:&row] && (_TouchOnRubyRR == YES || _TouchOnRubyRM == YES || _TouchOnRubyRL == YES )) {
        // the method verifies that the touch is on a cookie rather than on an empty square.
        Cookie *cookie = [self.level cookieAtColumn:column row:row];
        if (cookie != nil) {
            NSLog(@"_TouchOnRubyRR == YES || _TouchOnRubyRM == YES || _TouchOnRubyRL == YES");
            [self animateBricks:cookie];
        }

        BOOL RemoveRuby = YES;
        [self removeRubyWhenBrickIsTouched:RemoveRuby];
    }
   }
```

Comment: when do you call removeRubyWhenBrickIsTouched?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia When one of the sprites called bricks is being touched. (the bricks are "activated" when one of the rubies has been touched, then when the bricks are touched, the ruby that activated them disappears)

Comment: in the code I don't see that

Comment: @SimonePistecchia Sorry forgot to add the touchesBegan method. its included now :)

Comment: @SimonePistecchia I noticed is that  _RubyM.userInteractionEnabled = YES;  _RubyR.userInteractionEnabled = YES; _RubyL.userInteractionEnabled = NO; in - (void)removeRubyWhenBrickIsTouched: (BOOL)touched never happens for some reason